# Why in the first case displays debit = 'null', and the second the right amount

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Why in the first case displays debit = 'null', and the second the right amount

~

```
SELECT  o.kadastr,             /* Кадастровый номер */
        d.ar_inn,              /* ИНН арендатора */
        o.adres,               /* Адрес участка */
        r.name,                /* ФИО арендатора */
        o.pl_common,           /* Общая плащадь */
        d.arenda_beg,          /* Дата начала ареды */
        d.arenda_end,          /* Дата конца ареды */
        d.dogovor_kadst,       /* Общая кадастровая стоимость */
        rr.ref_str,             /* Вид разрешенного использования */
        ( SELECT SUM(rsh.debit) 
            FROM raschet rsh 
           WHERE rsh.s = 'C' 
             AND rsh.period_y = '2010' 
             AND rsh.dog_no = d.dog_no_fact) debet  /* Годовая арендная плата */
    FROM dogovor d
    INNER JOIN recviz r ON (r.inn_fact = d.ar_inn)
    LEFT JOIN object o ON (o.obj_no = d.obj_no)
    LEFT JOIN ras_refstr rr ON (rr.rasrefstrid = o.object_razr_isp)
```

~

```
SELECT SUM(rsh.debit) debit
FROM raschet rsh
WHERE r.dog_no = '1000' 
AND r.s = 'C' 
AND r.period_y = '2010'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debet` will be `NULL` because of this:

```
AND rsh.dog_no = d.dog_no_fact
```

If there's no `rs.dog_no` that matches the `d.dog_no_fact`, the subselect will return NULL.

Comment: Thank you. I was not attentive and just do not compare those fields table